# Angular - when refreshing page, slash is being appended to url

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I have the problem that whenever I refresh the page, a slash is being added to the url. Im being automatically (with timeout) directed to the state 'home' from the state 'intro'.When I go to home, instead of /home, I see /home/ which leads to: Cannot GET /home/.
Ive seen a suggestion somewhere in this forum to add    $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false); to fix that, however that doesn't work as well as nothing else I tried. Any ideas?Thanks!

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('intro', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'intro/intro.html',
    controller: 'introCtrl'
  });
});

app.config(function ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'home/home.html',
    controller: 'homeCtrl'
  });
});
```

my app.js file:

```
var app=angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.materialize']);
    app.config(function ($urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider,$urlMatcherFactoryProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
var app=angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.materialize']);

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider

  .state('app.intro', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: '/intro/intro.html',
            controller: "introCtrl"
        })

        .state('app.home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: '/home/home.html',
            controller: "homeCtrl"
        })

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

});
```

Comment: Solves the problem, when url is yourdomain.com/home show home html page